# Saving Data Issue, SharedPreferences

Tags: android

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView listView;
List all;
SharedPreferences sharedPref;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
    editor = sharedPref.edit();
    setListAdapter();
}
private void setListAdapter(){
    final String[] data = displayData().toString().split(",");
    ListAdapter listAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, data);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_AFTER_DESCENDANTS);
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}
public List displayData(){
    all = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        Map<String, ?> allMap = sharedPref.getAll();
        for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : allMap.entrySet()) {
            all.add(entry.getKey().toString() + ":" + entry.getValue().toString());
        }
    } catch(NullPointerException npe){
        all.add(" : ");
    }
    Log.i("understandCode", "displayData: " + all.toString());
    return all;
}

public void add(View view){
    editor.putString(" ", " ");
    editor.apply();
    setListAdapter();
}
private class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    String type;
    String content;
    public CustomAdapter(Context context, String[] resource) {
        super(context, R.layout.custom_row, resource);
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences
                (MainActivity.this);
        editor = sharedPref.edit();
    }
    EditText typeET;
    EditText contentET;
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        View customView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);
        String singleItem = getItem(position);
        typeET = (EditText) customView.findViewById(R.id.type);
        contentET = (EditText) customView.findViewById(R.id.content);
        String[] givenStrings = singleItem.split(":");
        try {
            typeET.setText(givenStrings[0]);
            contentET.setText(givenStrings[1]);
        }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException aioobe){
            typeET.setText(" ");
            contentET.setText(" ");
        }
        typeET.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                type = s.toString();
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                type = s.toString();
                save();
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });
        contentET.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                content = s.toString();
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                content = s.toString();
                save();
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


            }
        });
        return customView;
    }

    private void save() {
        editor.putString(type, content);
        editor.apply();
        Log.i("understandCode", type + ":" + content);

    }



}
```

}

Here is my log when I am editing my key, value:

```
05-04 17:52:52.107 11146-11146/com.x.xI/understandCode: [ my  mom!a said:y ]
05-04 17:52:52.462 11146-11146/com.valerdaita.myinfo I/understandCode: [ my mom!a said:yo ]
05-04 17:52:52.698 11146-11146/com.valerdaita.myinfo I/understandCode: [ my mom!a said:yol ]
05-04 17:52:52.897 11146-11146/com.x.x I/understandCode: [ my mom!a said:yolo ]
```

When I restart the Activity:

```
05-04 17:53:05.085 12056-12056/com.x.x I/understandCode: displayData: [ : ]
```

So, it is not showing the data that I saved. I really am having trouble identifying the problem because I know that my save functionality is working well because of the Log, but I cannot identify any problem with the displayer.

Comment: Not entirely sure, but are you sure that you're not receiving an NPE? In your `catch` statement, when an NPE occurs, you add a String value `" : "`. Can you put some other `Logs` inside the `try catch`. See if you are able to actually go through it?

Comment: I got a NullPointerException, if that is what you mean. There should not be any NullPointerException, though, if the app works properly. @trigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will definitely get NPE as you have not saved any values in your preferences yet.

Code flow is `setListAdapter() ->displayData() ->sharedPref.getAll()`.

In between this you are not adding any key-value pair to preferences. 
So why do you expect you'll not get NPE ?
Save some values before using `getAll()` if you don't want to get NPE.

Comment: ' my mom!a said: yolo' was what I saved. @ShadabAnsari

Comment: You are saving these values after the list is created but you are fetching the values even before the list is created. That's what I explained in my answer.

Comment: What should I change the code flow to? @ShadabAnsari

Comment: I wanted to be able to view the data at all ti!mes, from start to finish. @ShadabAnsari